# Rancher, Load Balancing and own domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, rancher

I have a question about rancher. I'm running my rancher on aws. I have created a new cluster with two nodes (workers) and I have deployed my docker images. Now I wanted to add Load Balancer, but I don't want to use xip.io domain but my own. I added my domain to route 53 and I wanted to make redirection from api.mydomain.com to Load Balancer. So, I added in route 53 new record and I used IP of my ec2 machine (I checked where the load balancer has been deployed in rancher)

The question is: What if I will want to change my nodes? My domain will stop working because I'm using the ip of ec2 machine. How should I point dns to my LB correctly (because I'm thinking that using the ip of ec2 machine is a not correct solution).

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to setup and configure the Route53 service from the rancher catalog.

After that, the load-balancer will automatically update its DNS in Route53.